# Extracting multiple table data using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="row margin_30">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="table-responsive table-border-radius">
<table class="table  table-hover result-table-new1 " style="margin:0">
<thead class="">
<tr class="">
<th style="text-align:center;">Pl</th>
<th>H.No</th>
<th>Horse/Pedigree</th>
<th>Desc</th>
<th>Trainer</th>
<th>Jockey</th>
<th>Wt</th>
<th>Al</th>
<th>Dr</th>
<th>Sh</th>
<th>Won By</th>
<th>Dist Win</th>
<th>Rtg</th>
<th>Odds</th>
<th>Time</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="">
<tr class="dividend_tr"  >
<td>1 </td>
<td style="text-align: center;">7 </td>
<td class="race_card_td"><h5 style="font-size:16px">
<a href="http://www.indiarace.com/Home/horseStatistics/55234/SILKEN 
 STRIKER">
 SILKEN STRIKER </a></h5>
<h6 class="margin_remove">Sussex(GB)-Flying Rani </h6>
</td>
<td>
4y b g </td>
<td>
Irfan Ghatala </td>
<td>
 Anjar Alam </td>
<td>
 56 </td>
<td>
 - </td>
<td>
 6 </td>
 <td>
 A </td>
<td>
5 1/2 </td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
12 </td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
1:14.57 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="dividend_tr"  >
<td>
2 </td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
5 </td>
<td class="race_card_td">
<h5 style="font-size:16px">
<a href="http://www.indiarace.com/Home/horseStatistics/55737/ULTIMATE 
POWER">
ULTIMATE POWER </a>
</h5>
<h6 class="margin_remove">
Epicentre(USA)-Methodical </h6>
</td>
<td>
4y b g </td>
<td>
V Lokanath </td>
<td>
Darshan R N </td>
<td>
57 </td>
<td>
-1 </td>
<td>
3 </td>
<td>
A </td>
<td>
5 </td>
<td>
5.5 </td>
<td>
14 </td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
1:15.47 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want the following output using Beautiful soup and want to store it in csv file. The actual page [http://www.indiarace.com/Home/racingCenterEvent?venueId=3&event_date=2018-08-10&race_type=RESULTS] has multiple tables and many rows. Also, I need to write a function to get data from different pages.

[Result][1]

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LYt8.jpg
```

Any help would be greatful.

Comment: Have you got any code so far you can show us? What have you tried?

Comment: for i in race_1:
    race1=i.find_all(class_='dividend_tr')
    for row in race1:
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        links = row.find('a')
        pl_no = cells[0].get_text().strip('\n')
        hno= cells[1].get_text().strip('\n')
        horse=links.contents[0].strip('\n')
        age=cells[3].get_text().strip('\n')
        trainer=cells[4].get_text().strip('\n')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple you need find all tables then iterate tr and td as per your requirement. You can use pandas to save the scraped data. i have parse the tables for you (the rest you have to do)...check the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.indiarace.com/Home/racingCenterEvent?venueId=3&event_date=2018-08-10&race_type=RESULTS'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={
    'class':'result-table-new1'})
for i in table:
    tr = i.find_all('tr')
    for td in tr:
        print(td.text.replace('\n', ' '))
```

Comment: Thank You Sohan for your help. Later I could figure out the answer but I ended up writing a long loop. Your solution is optimal.